# Upgrade Issue - no matching package found. zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 not found

Tags: magento-upgrade

I am upgrading from Magento 2.1.14 to Magento 2.2.6,  when I run composer update I get the following error.  Appreciate your help.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Answer (score 0):

Please update the `zendframework/zend-stdlib` version in your `magento_root_dir/composer.json` to what the error shows, i.e. `"zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^2.7.7"` and then run `composer update` command.